# Disable specific permission in android app with xposed

Tags: android, xposed

i am looking for a way to disable specific permission from the installed app with xposed hook

as with root it is not possible but with xposed everything on runtime at fly,
anybody knows what should i hook to disable permission

code help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need a Xposed module:
Look at /system/etc/permissions/platform.xml. It's contains a map between a permission and the gids that implement that permission. If you remove the gids, the permission will be granted but won't add actual capabilities to the app.